# Creating new column in Dataframe using dict and map gives only NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe as such,

```
       Rank % Renewable
Country     
China   1   19.754910
Japan   3   10.232820
Canada  6   61.945430
Germany 7   17.901530
India   8   14.969080
France  9   17.020280
Italy   11  33.667230
Spain   12  37.968590
Iran    13  5.707721
Brazil  15  69.648030
```

I use a dictionary to map values into a new column called continent using the following code I found in an similar answer,

```
df['continent'] = pd.Series(df.index.values).map(ContinentDict)
```

being `ContinentDict`,

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
              'United States':'North America', 
              'Japan':'Asia', 
              'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
              'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
              'Canada':'North America', 
              'Germany':'Europe', 
              'India':'Asia',
              'France':'Europe', 
              'South Korea':'Asia', 
              'Italy':'Europe', 
              'Spain':'Europe', 
              'Iran':'Asia',
              'Australia':'Australia', 
              'Brazil':'South America'}
```

All the new items in column `continent` are NaNs, can anyone help me here?

Comment: @MaxU I don't think there is a `map` method for `index` objects you need a `Series`

Comment: @EdChum, yes, you are right! We can do something like: `df.index.map(lambda x: ContinentDict.get(x))`, but your solution should be faster...

Comment: @MaxU I didn't see this comment.  Yes, your concept works.  But no need to pass the lambda, just pass `ContinentDict.get`, see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
In[90]:
df['continent'] = df.index.to_series().map(ContinentDict)
df

Out[90]: 
         Rank  % Renewable      continent
Country                                  
China       1    19.754910           Asia
Japan       3    10.232820           Asia
Canada      6    61.945430  North America
Germany     7    17.901530         Europe
India       8    14.969080           Asia
France      9    17.020280         Europe
Italy      11    33.667230         Europe
Spain      12    37.968590         Europe
Iran       13     5.707721           Asia
Brazil     15    69.648030  South America
```

What you tried:

```
In[91]:
pd.Series(df.index.values).map(ContinentDict)

Out[91]: 
0             Asia
1             Asia
2    North America
3           Europe
4             Asia
5           Europe
6           Europe
7           Europe
8             Asia
9    South America
dtype: object
```

generates `NaN` because you're constructing a `Series` from the numpy values so the index returned is the auto-generated `RangeIndex` so when it tries to align against your df, it fails so all rows become `NaN`

Comment: It works, you are fast, 'You can accept the answer in 3 minutes" :)

Comment: Now I understand difference. +1. To make OP's method work need to assign index manually i.e `pd.Series(df.index.values,index=df.index).map(ContinentDict)`

Comment: @Bharathshetty true but it seems redundant to create a new `Series` object when `Index` objects already have a `to_series` which will take the existing index

Comment: I totally agree. It was just to make the approach work. Votes say that `to_series` still the best.

Comment: @Bharathshetty you can use `map` on the `index`.  See answer below.  +1 btw (-:

Answer (score 4):

**For completeness:**

`pd.Index` definitely has a [**`map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) method.  However, as of pandas 0.20.3, it only takes a callable.  That means it does not work with a dictionary.  We can change that by passing a callable to it.  In fact, a dictionary already has the appropriate method for us.  Namely, [**`dict.get`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```
df['continent'] = df.index.map(ContinentDict.get)

df

         Rank  % Renewable      continent
Country                                  
China       1    19.754910           Asia
Japan       3    10.232820           Asia
Canada      6    61.945430  North America
Germany     7    17.901530         Europe
India       8    14.969080           Asia
France      9    17.020280         Europe
Italy      11    33.667230         Europe
Spain      12    37.968590         Europe
Iran       13     5.707721           Asia
Brazil     15    69.648030  South America
```

Comment: Nice really nice. I had what MaxU posted in comment.  Didn't know this was possible